Bank robbery film with explosions masked by a street parade/ carnival
Please help a friend and I. We both recall seeing a film when we were kids in the 80s where there was a bank robbery. Explosives were used to enter the vault and the sound of the explosions were timed with the beating of drums/ music in a street carnival/ parade that was going on at street level. 
There were also some giant puppets that were used to smuggle to money out, so nobody would notice.
Most likely 70/80s film, in English. I recall it being American, but my friend disagrees. 
If you can help with this at all, I'd be most grateful. Its been really bugging me what the film was called. Sorry for the very sketchy details. 

Do you remember any actors? Or quotes?

I'm sorry I don't Dominic but thank you for contributing.

Actually, this sounds exactly like The Caper of the Golden Bulls (AKA Carnival of Thieves) from 1967, where a group of robbers led by ex-pilot Peter Churchman rob a bank during the Fiesta of San Fermin in Pamplona (known for its traditional Running of the Bulls) using this very same method:

During the fiesta, Churchman's men carry concealed explosives and tools during the famed Running of the Bulls, veering off into an alley during the event. Churchman has broken into a bank and, using the dynamite, he blows open a safe, timing the explosion with a cannon's shot that is a traditional rite during the festival.

They then proceed to stash the money inside a huge hollow festival puppet. Here's the trailer (dubbed in a foreign language) where you can see the festival, those giant puppets and the robbers timing the explosion with the cannon:




hopefully the OP confirms this! Looks like it might be it.

@DominicG. I dunno, the OP hasn't been seen in a month and a half, they vanished 2 days after posting the Q. But well, hope springs eternal, so I answered anyway. ;)

Screw it, this satisfies my craving for the answer.  Bounty awarded.

Wow, that's nice of you :) Much obliged! I hope it's the right one too.

Perhaps it's Grand Slam? It's a 1967 film that uses the Rio Carnival in Brazil to help cover their tracks.

Thank you Jonathan. I'm going to look that one up immediately. I'll report back.....

I thought the whole point there was that they were trying to overcome a sound-sensitive alarm and had to be as quiet as possible.
